# How do I test a get_date function using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I got this function called get_date in a project and I'm requested to test it via pytest.

```
def get_date(string):
    try:
        date_str = input(string)
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return date
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format")
        return get_date(string)
```

I previously had:

```
def get_date(string):
    while True:
        try:
            date_str = input(string)
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            return date
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format")
            raise
```

```
def test_get_date(monkeypatch):
    inputs = [
        "12/06/2023",
        "12-06-2023",
        "2023/06/12",
        "2023/17/87",
        "hello",
        "2023-06-12",
    ]
    input_values = iter(inputs)
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", lambda _: next(input_values))

    # Test first input ("12/06/2023")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

    # Test second input ("12-06-2023")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

    # Test third input ("2023/06/12")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

    # Test fourth input ("hello")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

    # Test fifth output ("2023-06-12")
    assert get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ") == datetime.date(2023, 6, 12)
```

The issue with this is that when the ValueError is raised the program crashes instead of re-prompting the user for new input, which is something that really can't happen.

I thought of changing the function to a is_date function that would return a bool, but that would involve changing the whole program, which is something I'm not looking for since everything works just fine.

Also, this is a void function and because of it I can't use the usual assert method. I did some research and found this iter method which I'm not sure is the optimal way to do so.

I really hope you can help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

By adding raise, you re-raise the ValueError after printing the error msg and thus it crashes.

so if you want the program to repromt for the user to re-enter data remove the 'raise' statement in the get-date function.

Hope This Helps

Here is the whole code:

```
import datetime
import pytest

def get_date(string):
    while True:
        try:
            date_str = input(string)
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            return date
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format")

def test_get_date(monkeypatch, capfd):
    inputs = [
        "12/06/2023",
        "12-06-2023",
        "2023/06/12",
        "2023/17/87",
        "hello",
        "2023-06-12",
    ]
    input_values = iter(inputs)
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", lambda _: next(input_values))

    # invalid inputs test
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
        captured = capfd.readouterr()
        assert "Please enter a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format" in captured.out

    # valid input test
    assert get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ") == date(2023, 6, 12)
```

capfd.readouterr() allows you to capture the output that would have been printed to the console.
if you wanna more about it [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html)

Hope This Is Helpful

Comment: Yeah, I know. But that is the issue. I want to catch the invalid input in the test file

Comment: That would be great, yes

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that encapsulates the re-prompting the user in case of an input error inside the get_input function.

```
def get_input(string):
    date_str = input(string)
    while True:
        try:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format")
            date_str = input(string)
    return date
```

Comment: How would the test function look like in the invalid date part?

Comment: You would have to modify your test cases to account for the fact that the only valid return is a datetime object.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the function to a boolean. Instead just take the date string as an argument and move the user input outside to a separate function.

`get_date` function without user input:

```py
def get_date(date_str):
    try:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return date
    except ValueError:
        raise
```

Testing:

```py
def test_get_date():
    assert get_date("2023-06-12") == datetime.date(2023, 6, 12)

    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("stuff")

    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("2023/06/12")

    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_date("2023/69/420")
```

Add the user input back into your code before you call `get_date` and hand it off as as the `data_str` argument.

Comment: I also thought of this but it really involves change a lot. I was looking for a solution that kept the function I have. Also, as a ValueError is raised the program is going to crash, no?

Comment: ValueError only gets raised if the date format is wrong. You can keep the input inside get_date but it's going to be more annoying to test.

Comment: I know, but what if the user inputs a wrong value error and I pass it to the function to get checked? It will raise the ValueError and therefore crash the program

Comment: Don't you want the program to stop if a bad value is given? If for some reason you don't just change the 'raise' after 'except' to 'pass'

Comment: I don't want it to stop, but I want it to be flaged (idk if that's the term) so I catch it in a test file. If I pass, I can't catch it with pytest.raises

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea in your original code - you just need to skip calling get_date for all the intermediate cases, because the execution of `get_date()` will handle those bad inputs, and then prompt for the next input.

Then at the end we can assert that the list of inputs was exhausted.

```
#script.py
import datetime

def get_date(string):
    # Use a loop, not recursion
    while True:
        try:
            date_str = input(string)
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a date in the YYYY-MM-DD format")
    
    return date
```

```
#test_script.py
import pytest
import datetime
from script import get_date

def test_get_date(monkeypatch):
    inputs = [
        "12/06/2023",
        "12-06-2023",
        "2023/06/12",
        "2023/17/87",
        "hello",
        "2023-06-12",
    ]
    input_values = iter(inputs)
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.input", lambda _: next(input_values))

    # Test that all other inputs were handled and we accept the last one
    assert get_date("Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ") == datetime.date(2023, 6, 12)

    with pytest.raises(StopIteration):
        _ = input("Verify inputs list is exhausted")
```

If the inputs list is not exhausted (there are values after an "accepted" input), then Pytest will fail with

```
FAILED test_script.py::test_get_date - Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'StopIteration'>
```